# Huawei usb stick troubles on ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, usb, mobile-broadband

I have Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with kernel: 4.4.0-45-generic.
I have USB stick modem refirmwared for the cellular company owns the modem.
The problem is that often, I need several time to reinsert the device, reboot computer or/and restart network-manager, for get Mobile Broadband option in NetworkManager widget in top of screen...
Maybe can you suggest drivers or other solution?

This is info from hwinfo related to network:

```
>> net.1: get network data
  net interface: name = lo, path = /class/net/lo
    type = 772
    carrier = 1
    hw_addr = 00:00:00:00:00:00
    GDRVINFO ethtool error: Operation not supported
    ethtool private flags: 0
  net interface: name = ppp0, path = /class/net/ppp0
    type = 512
    carrier = 1
    hw_addr =
    GDRVINFO ethtool error: Operation not supported
    ethtool private flags: 0
  net interface: name = enp5s0, path = /class/net/enp5s0
    type = 1
    carrier = 0
    hw_addr = 78:24:af:20:d9:d1
    net device: path = /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:05:00.0
    net driver: name = r8169, path = /bus/pci/drivers/r8169
    ethtool private flags: 0
  net interface: name = wlp4s0, path = /class/net/wlp4s0
    type = 1
    carrier = 0
    hw_addr = b8:ee:65:e2:be:c3
    net device: path = /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0
    net driver: name = ath9k, path = /bus/pci/drivers/ath9k
    ethtool private flags: 0
  net interface: name = wwx001e101f0000, path = /class/net/wwx001e101f0000
    type = 1
    hw_addr = 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
    net device: path = /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2
    net driver: name = huawei_cdc_ncm, path = /bus/usb/drivers/huawei_cdc_ncm
    ethtool private flags: 0
  wwx001e101f0000: ethtool link state: 0
```

This is from lshw:

```
olga@olga-comp:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path           Device           Class          Description
==============================================================
                                    system         X750JN (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
/0                                  bus            X750JN
/0/0                                memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/25                               memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/26                               memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/27                               memory         6MiB L3 cache
/0/28                               processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
/0/29                               memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/29/0                             memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
/0/29/1                             memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous
/0/100                              bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
/0/100/1                            bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller
/0/100/1.1                          bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller
/0/100/1.1/0                        display        GM108M [GeForce 840M]
/0/100/2                            display        4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/3                            multimedia     Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
/0/100/14                           bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
/0/100/14/0        usb2             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1        usb1             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/1      scsi10           storage        HUAWEI_MOBILE
/0/100/14/1/1/0    /dev/sr1         disk           SCSI CD-ROM
/0/100/14/1/1/0/1                   volume         31KiB Apple partition map
/0/100/14/1/1/0/2                   volume         27MiB Apple HFS
/0/100/14/1/1/1    /dev/sdc         disk           SCSI Disk
/0/100/14/1/2                       input          USB Optical Mouse
/0/100/14/1/5                       generic        USB2.0-CRW
/0/100/14/1/a                       multimedia     USB Camera
/0/100/16                           communication  8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
/0/100/1b                           multimedia     8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                           bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c.2                         bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3
/0/100/1c.2/0      wlp4s0           network        QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1c.3                         bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4
/0/100/1c.3/0      enp5s0           network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1f                           bridge         HM86 Express LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                         storage        8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1f.3                         bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/1               scsi2            storage        
/0/1/0.0.0         /dev/cdrom       disk           DVD-RAM UJ8E2 S
/0/2               scsi4            storage        
/0/2/0.0.0         /dev/sda         disk           1TB ST1000LM024 HN-M
/0/2/0.0.0/1       /dev/sda1        volume         99MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/2/0.0.0/2       /dev/sda2        volume         899MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/2/0.0.0/3       /dev/sda3        volume         127MiB reserved partition
/0/2/0.0.0/4       /dev/sda4        volume         372GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/2/0.0.0/5       /dev/sda5        volume         537GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/2/0.0.0/6       /dev/sda6        volume         20GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/3               scsi5            storage        
/0/3/0.0.0         /dev/sdb         disk           1TB ST1000LM024 HN-M
/0/3/0.0.0/1       /dev/sdb1        volume         465GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/3/0.0.0/2       /dev/sdb2        volume         230GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/3/0.0.0/3       /dev/sdb3        volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/3/0.0.0/4       /dev/sdb4        volume         226GiB EXT4 volume
/0/3/0.0.0/5       /dev/sdb5        volume         8076MiB Linux swap volume
/1                 wwx001e101f0000  network        Ethernet interface
```

This is last messages from dmesg related to modem:

```
[  455.747911] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  470.307849] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  470.436817] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14fe
[  470.436821] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  470.436823] usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[  470.436824] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[  470.436825] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[  470.469376] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  470.469788] scsi host9: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  471.473974] scsi 9:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  471.474428] scsi 9:0:0:1: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  471.475698] sr 9:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[  471.475855] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[  471.475939] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[  471.476134] sd 9:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[  471.477325] sd 9:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  471.613924] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  472.175764] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  472.304732] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1506
[  472.304736] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  472.304738] usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[  472.304740] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[  472.374843] option 1-1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  472.374943] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  472.375013] option 1-1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  472.375069] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  472.375369] usb-storage 1-1:1.3: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  472.375455] scsi host10: usb-storage 1-1:1.3
[  472.375753] usb-storage 1-1:1.4: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  472.375926] scsi host11: usb-storage 1-1:1.4
[  472.409279] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[  472.410752] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[  472.514260] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-1:1.2: MAC-Address: 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[  472.514264] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-1:1.2: setting rx_max = 16384
[  472.521551] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-1:1.2: NDP will be placed at end of frame for this device.
[  472.521655] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-1:1.2: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[  472.521819] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-1:1.2 wwan0: register 'huawei_cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, Huawei CDC NCM device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[  472.522501] usbcore: registered new interface driver huawei_cdc_ncm
[  472.527916] huawei_cdc_ncm 1-1:1.2 wwx001e101f0000: renamed from wwan0
[  473.381923] scsi 10:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  473.381970] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  473.383093] sr 10:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[  473.383253] sr 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[  473.383339] sr 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[  473.383622] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[  473.386368] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  475.637025] sr 10:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  475.637029] sr 10:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  475.637031] sr 10:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  475.637033] sr 10:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8d fe 00 00 02 00
[  475.637035] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 145400
[  475.643294] sr 10:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  475.643297] sr 10:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  475.643298] sr 10:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  475.643300] sr 10:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 8d fe 00 00 02 00
[  475.643302] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr1, sector 145400
[  475.643303] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 18175, async page read
[  475.756160] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[  475.756415] ISO 9660 Extensions: IEEE_P1282
[  488.391807] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[  488.393749] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
```

And, this is content of network manager configuration file:

```
olga@olga-comp:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections$ sudo cat Megafon\ RUS
[connection]
id=Megafon RUS
uuid=7b5d723f-2b41-4a0e-95f9-7f29d824f7c8
type=gsm
autoconnect=false
permissions=user:ubuntu:;
secondaries=

[gsm]
apn=internet
number=*99#
password-flags=1
username=gdata

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Comment: What is the output of `ModemManager --version` ?

Comment: Was it working for you on Ubuntu 16.04 for a while or is it the same all the time? I had a HUAWEI USB modem which worked fine on Ubuntu 14.10 and when I installed 16.04 I had the same problems you describe - it was hard to get it working and then the device disappeared and reappeared always asking for the PIN to unlock it. I was not able to fix it (i tried for 3-4 days) so I bought a tp-link m5350 (it was my father's in law laptop) and he is happy with it.

Comment: GAD3R: ModemManager 1.4.12

Comment: Zina: I used it just on 16.04...